# How can I include several contacts in a single vcard(.vcf) file using rails and vpim gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, vcf-vcard, vpim

I have multiple contact datas in my website that I want to include in a single .vcf file to download. I implemented it one by one but I want to add the option to download all the contacts together not one by one.

Is possible to implement a method to download all the contacts at once in a single .vcf file? or I see other possibility. Make a function that receives a list of contacts and makes and vcard for each one, but the problem is that I have to save it in a buffer and then make a .zip or .rar file with all vcards and then download it. But I don't know how to implement it.

How can I do it using rails and vpim gem or other gem?
thanks

**UPDATE**

I wrote a post explaining my solution.
http://tomasmax.blogspot.com.es/2011/12/modificar-la-gem-vpim-para-introducir.html

Comment: I get it modifiying vpim gem code.

Comment: Hello Thomas, can you please share what you did to include multiple contacts in single .vcf file?

Comment: Excuse me varunvalan I haven't read your question. My solution is in this link, it is in spanish but I think it is not difficult to understand, if you need help do not hesitate to contact me. http://tomasmax.blogspot.com.es/2011/12/modificar-la-gem-vpim-para-introducir.html